# "Priority stack" (a hybrid of priority queue and stack) in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, priority-queue

I need "priority stack" datastructure (like priority queue, but more like LIFE like a stack) in Python 3.

I know `queue.PriorityQueue` but found no thing like `queue.PriorityStack`.

Comment: What exactly would a priority stack do? Have you tried writing one?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I think, it should be like stack but higher priority entries "float" above lesser priority ones

Comment: If the "priority" determines the order of popping the items, then how is it different from a priority queue?

Comment: @neerad29 It should be LIFO rather than FIFO for entries of the same priority. That's is the essence of the difference

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You could implement this as a priority queue of stacks. That is, each element in the priority queue is a stack of items with the same priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create an object that contains the actual data you want to insert, and a sequence number that is incremented every time you do an insert. So you have an object that looks something like this:

```
queueObject
    actual_data
    sequence_number
    priority
```

When you want to insert something into the priority queue, you create this object with a new sequence number. Something like:

```
function insert(data, priority)
    obj = new queuedObject(data, priority, ++globalSequence)
    pq.insert(obj)
```

With that and a custom comparator, you can just use the standard Python heapq object. Just make sure that the comparator compares the priority and the sequence number.

You can use a timestamp in place of the sequence number, if you like. Either way, assuming your comparator is correct, this will ensure that items with the same priority are dequeued in LIFO order.